# Is there any way that I can Embed sharepoint folder/list on external website (react and node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I am looking to get a view of SharePoint file manager inside my website without moving to any external tab, I also want to perform CRUD operation on those files. I would be using react js for frontend and node.js for backend. Is there any kind of plugin or other way I could achieve this functionality?

File Manager

[image: 1]